# Is it possible to call a function outside of the jQuery UI slider element with ui.value as the argument?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Is it somehow possible to call a function outside of the jQuery UI slider element with ui.value as the argument?

The way I do it now:

```
 $("#id").slider({  
slide: function(event,ui) {
$("#another_id").val(ui.value);
...other statements...
}
});
```

This is the way I tried to solve the problem but when I tried this the handle of the slider widget wouldn't move...:

```
function insertValue(value) {
$("#another_id").val(value);
...other statements...
}

$("#id").slider({   
slide: function(event,ui) {
insertValue(ui.value);
}
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: The code looks fine, can you please provide a fiddle that reproduces the problem? Also check your browser console for any Javascript errors (Ctrl+Shift+J)

Comment: You are absolutely right, the browser console showed what was wrong. Thanks!